# Procedure to add element to JSON array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have been trying to add an element to a JSON array, in which the JSON array is designed with the following attributes:

```
 /* 
var courses = [{
        "dept": "CSC",
        "id": "3102",
        "instructor": "Kooima",
        "Location": "230 Turead"
    }
]
```

and the JavaScript code segment that performs the task is implemented as:

```
        var newCourse = {};
        courses.push(newCourse);
        var count = courses.length - 1;
        courses[count].dept = dept;
        courses[count].id = num;
        courses[count].instructor = prof;
        courses[count].Location = loc;
```

However, I believe this may not be in the correct order/missing further code to properly add the element to the list, and wanted to make sure I was possibly not neglecting an essential component.

Answer (score 1):

What you did will work fine. Personaly I prefer the following way;

```
    var newCourse = {};
    newCourse.dept = dept;
    newCourse.id = num;
    newCourse.instructor = prof;
    newCourse.Location = loc;
    courses.push(newCourse);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing like JSON array, It's simple javascript array which you can create in the following manner.

Just push the new course every time

```
courses.push({
  "dept": dept,
  "id": id,
  "instructor": prof,
  "Location": loc
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick and simple

```
courses.push({
    "dept": dept,
    "id": num,
    "instructor": prof,
    "Location": loc
});
```